# Есть ли альтернатива out в C# для python?

Tags: c#, python

Есть функция в которой через out указывается куда должны отправится значения после вычислений.
условно:

```
Method (int[,] array, out int value, out int x, out int y)
{...}
```

Как такое реализовать в python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Python функция может вернуть кортеж значений:

```py
def method(array):
    return 1, 2, 3

value, x, y = method(...)
```

Кстати, в свежем C# тоже так можно делать.